# Oracle entity in VS entity framework doesnt update the primary key in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, oracle, entity-framework

I have an entity called Tree, which has a primary key called Id (with StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity) that when using the following code, correctly inserts into the database.

```
   using(TestContainer tss = new TestContainer())
   {
      Tree tree = new Tree()
      {
         Name = "TestTree"
      };

      tss.Trees.AddObject(tree);
      tss.SaveChanges();
   }
```

I have a backing sequence + trigger to handle the auto incremented primary key Id. I have verified that this actually inserts into the database correctly.

Calling `tss.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, tree);` does not update the object (the 'Id' field is still 0). Any ideas?

```
        <EntityType Name="Tree">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="Id" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="HeuristicCulls" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.TreeHeuristicCull" FromRole="Tree" ToRole="HeuristicCull" />
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="Type" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="PR_T" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.PR_TTree" FromRole="Tree" ToRole="PR_T" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="TreeItems" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.TreeTreeItem" FromRole="Tree" ToRole="TreeItem" />
          <Property Type="Byte" Name="IsRoot" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Type="Byte" Name="IsProductRoot" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="TreeProducts" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.T_TP" FromRole="Tree" ToRole="TreeProducts" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="TreeItem">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="Id" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Questions" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.TI_Q" FromRole="TreeItem" ToRole="Question" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="SubmitRules" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.SubmitRuleTreeItem" FromRole="TreeItem" ToRole="SubmitRule" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="PR_TI" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.PR_TITreeItem" FromRole="TreeItem" ToRole="PR_TI" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Tree" Relationship="TOPSSSimpleSelect.TreeTreeItem" FromRole="TreeItem" ToRole="Tree" />
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="TreeId" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Type="Byte" Name="IsRoot" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
```

Comment: If you open EDMX as XML can you verify that SSDL part also marks key with `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `identity`?

Comment: I believe so. The first post has been updated with the XML.

Answer (score 6):

Open up the .edmx file with the XML editor and look for the section that begins with the following line:

```
<!-- SSDL content -->
```

Below should be an EntityType tag and in it is a definition of the database table. Make sure that the property for your ID column has *StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"* in it.

Below this SSDL section is a CSDL section that looks similar, but defines the C# object that represents this entity. The visual designer only seems to fill in the StoreGeneratedPatternin this section, but not the SSDL section.

**EDIT WITH SAMPLE**

Here's a sample EDMX file for an Employee entity, with nothing but an ID, FirstName, and LastName property. The ID is the field you want auto generated by the database. Note that there are two different places where StoreGeneratedPattern is needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="Store" Alias="Self" Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="10g"
              xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="StoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="EMPLOYEE" EntityType="Store.EMPLOYEE" store:Type="Tables" Schema="TESTSPACE" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="EMPLOYEE">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
          </Key>
          <!-- The below property requires StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" -->
          <Property Name="ID" Type="number" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" Precision="10" />
          <Property Name="FIRST_NAME" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="LAST_NAME" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="255" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm"
              xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration"
              xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" Namespace="Model" Alias="Self"
              xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
        <EntityContainer Name="ModelContainer" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="Employees1" EntityType="Model.Employee" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Employee">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
          </Key>
          <!-- The below property requires StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" -->
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="ID" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="FirstName" MaxLength="255" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="LastName" MaxLength="255" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="StoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="ModelContainer">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Employees1">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Model.Employee">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="EMPLOYEE">
                <ScalarProperty Name="LastName" ColumnName="LAST_NAME" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FirstName" ColumnName="FIRST_NAME" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
    <edmx:Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </edmx:Connection>
    <edmx:Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="True" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="True" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </edmx:Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <edmx:Diagrams>
      <Diagram Name="Model">
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="Model.Employee" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="0.75"
                         Height="1.4279589843749996" />
      </Diagram>
    </edmx:Diagrams>
  </edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: I get the error: 'The "StoreGeneratedPattern" attribute is not allowed' when I try this. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sample XML file. There are two places the require StoreGeneratedPattern, and I've marked them with comments. Make sure you have both.

Comment: I've run into the same issue, and this is how we resolved it. We ended up building a VS add-in to read the EDMX XML and look for entities with this problem, and edit and re-save the XML whenever the designer was used to make changes.

Comment: This looks like it has been fixed. I just adjusted the setting in the Model Designer and it updated the XML